# Keystone/Apollo/React: 1 useMutation for several creations issue

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, keystonejs

I tried to create multiple products inside one single order creation.

Actually it works here manually through the GraphQL tool :

```
mutation {
    createOrder(
      data: { 
        orderName: "Order 1"
        products: { create: [{ name: "Product 1" }, { name: "Product 2" }]}
      }) {
      id
      name
      products {
          name
      }
      }
    }
```

But I can’t figure out how to write this in a useMutation hook from Apollo and how to pass the variables inside.
I tried something like this but it’s still not complete, and I can’t find so for any doc mentioning how:

```
const CREATE_ORDER = gql`
  mutation CREATE_ORDER(
    $orderName: String!
    $name: String!
  ) {
    createOrder(
      data: {
        orderName: $orderName
            products: { create: [{name: $name}, {name: $name}] }
      }
    ) {
      id
      orderName
      products {
          name
      }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And as a variable objects I would pass this:

```
const [createOrder, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(CREATE_ORDER, {
    variables: {
      orderName: 'Order X',
      products: [{ name: 'Burger'}, { name: 'Pizza'}],
    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: prepare entire `$data:someCreateOrderInput` variable

Comment: Thanks for your feedback !
It helped me find the solution

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked (and I pass an array of objects in the $data):

```
const CREATE_QUOTE = gql`
  mutation CREATE_QUOTE(
    $date: String!
    $total: Int!
    $data: [CartItemCreateInput]
  ) {
    createQuote(
      data: { date: $date, total: $total, cartItems: { create: $data } }
    ) {
      id
      date
      total
    }
  }
`;
```